# Spark Structure Streaming job failing in cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark-sql-2.4.1 v in my application.

While writing data on to hdfs folder I am facing this issue in spark-streaming application

**Error:**

```
    yarn.Client: Deleted staging directory hdfs://dev/user/xyz/.sparkStaging/application_1575699597805_47
    20/02/24 14:02:15 ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user= xyz, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp/hadoop-admin":admin:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
    .
    .
    .
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=xyz, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp/hadoop-admin":admin:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:350)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:251)
```

While writing data on to HDFS folder I am facing this issue in spark-streaming application. When I run in yarn-cluster mode I face this issue i.e.

```
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
```

But when I run in “yarn-client” mode it runs fine i.e.

```
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode client \
```

What is the root cause of this problem?

Fundamental question here, why it is trying to write in "`/tmp/hadoop-admin/`" instead of respective user directory i.e. `hdfs://qa2/user/xyz/`?

I have come across this fix:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26825

How can I implement it in my spark-sql application?

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the working `--deploy-mode client` and the failing `--deploy-mode cluster` cases is the location of the driver. In client deploy mode, the driver runs on the machine you execute `spark-submit` (which is usually an edge node that is configured to use a YARN cluster, but it is not part of it) while in cluster deploy mode the driver runs as part of a YARN cluster (one of the nodes under control of YARN).

It looks like you've got a misconfigured edge node.

---

I'd not be surprised if a regular Spark SQL-only Spark application would be failing too. I'd not be surprised to hear that it has nothing to do with a streaming query (Spark Structured Streaming) and would fail for any Spark application.

Comment: Firstly, you should not use HDFS/S3 for a temporary directory that should be as fast as SSD (that's the location of data blocks among other temporary things). Secondly, that seems more HDFS-related than Spark's. Can't help here.

Comment: `/tmp/hadoop-admin/nm-local-dir/usercache/myproj/appcache/application_1575699597805_47873` is the path of your Spark application deployed to YARN. It's a YARN thing (not much Spark's) and I can't help with it. Sorry.